# Deploying Jekyll Website With Github

Tags: github, jekyll

I'm use Github pages to host my jekyll website, and I'm wondering if there's a better solution to my deployment workflow.

Currently I build the site, then I delete everything in my git repo folder except .git and then copy everything from _site/ into the repo, commit and push.

Is there a way to get jekyll to build the site directly into the git repo without wiping the .git folder?

I've been googling it and have seen the syncing techniques and whatnot, but was hoping there was a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your Jekyll site into your pages repo. GitHub will detect that you're using Jekyll and generate the site for you automatically.

Comment: Shouldn't the branch name be gh-pages as well?